# How can I manipulate the range of an input object in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

NW noobie here. How can I increase/decrease the value of a range element via Nighwatch?

I tried sendKeys to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the way that worked for me is executing javascript in the browser to change the value of input=range, and then trigger the change event

```
   .execute(function(data) {
        try {
            // statements

            p = document.querySelector("input[type='range']");
            p.value = 41;
            event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent("change", true, true);
            p.dispatchEvent(event);
        } catch(e) {
            // statements
            console.log(e);
        }


        return true;
    }, [], function(result) {

    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me fully. It did move the slider but did not trigger the change event. Is that browser specific?

Comment: yes it is browser specific here you have a complete guide of event trigger for all browsers in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by triggering a drag event on the input type range

Comment: I realize this was answered 4 years ago but I'm trying something similary ... using try/catch in an .execute function ... but it doesn't seem like try/catch is working.  Specifically, where there is an error it is not logged to the console.  Clarification - the error IS logged but it goes to the web console rather than to the console in my IDE (VSCode).